# Does XUnit share fixture instances across test classes?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, fixtures, xunit.net

This is a simplified version of some code I have:

```cs
public class FixtureData
{
    public object SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class TestForNull : IClassFixture<FixtureData>
{
    private readonly FixtureData _data;

    public TestForNull(FixtureData data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestForNull()
    {
        _data.SomeValue = null;
        Assert.Null(_data.SomeValue);
    }
}

public class TestForObject : IClassFixture<FixtureData>
{
    private readonly FixtureData _data;

    public TestForObject(FixtureData data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestForObject()
    {
        Assert.NotNull(_data.SomeValue);
    }
}
```

Both classes are not marked with any collection attribute. They both belong to the same assembly.

I am seeing these test fail (but only sporadically), which can only be explained by XUnit sharing the `FixtureData` instance across test classes, and `TestForNull` running first (since it has side effects).

However, the [XUnit documentation](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html) makes it clear that class fixtures are to "shared object instance across tests in a **single** class".

Is this a bug? Should I change the way in which I'm using the fixtures?

I'm using xUnit for .NET Core 2.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ruben Bartelink says in his response, "SELECT is not broken", meaning that this is a very core feature that XUnit, a well proven test framework and it's very very unlikely that the issue is on their side.

Furthermore, digging into XUnit code, this is what it does to generate class fixtures: ([Source](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/c54cc52ffb275c81afed022521870193bbca6c39/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/XunitTestClassRunner.cs#L141-L152))

```cs
var createClassFixtureAsyncTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var interfaceType in testClassTypeInfo.ImplementedInterfaces.Where(i => i.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IClassFixture<>)))
    createClassFixtureAsyncTasks.Add(CreateClassFixtureAsync(interfaceType.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments.Single()));

if (TestClass.TestCollection.CollectionDefinition != null)
{
    var declarationType = ((IReflectionTypeInfo)TestClass.TestCollection.CollectionDefinition).Type;
    foreach (var interfaceType in declarationType.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Where(i => i.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IClassFixture<>)))
        createClassFixtureAsyncTasks.Add(CreateClassFixtureAsync(interfaceType.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments.Single()));
}

await Task.WhenAll(createClassFixtureAsyncTasks);
```

From the calls to `CreateClassFixtureAsync` it's easy to tell that class fixtures are **regenerated each time** for a test case.

#### Then why the behavior I observed?

I accidentally simplified more in my example that I should have. I found that this might be a better example of what was going on:

```cs
public class FixtureData
{
    public object SomeValue => HiddenSingleton.Instance.SomeValue;
}

public class HiddenSingleton
{
    private static HiddenSingleton _instance;
    public static HiddenSingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance != null) return _instance;

            _instance = new HiddenSingleton();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public object SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class TestForNull : IClassFixture<FixtureData>
{
    private readonly FixtureData _data;

    public TestForNull(FixtureData data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestForNull()
    {
        _data.SomeValue = null;
        Assert.Null(_data.SomeValue);
    }
}

public class TestForObject : IClassFixture<FixtureData>
{
    private readonly FixtureData _data;

    public TestForObject(FixtureData data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestForObject()
    {
        Assert.NotNull(_data.SomeValue);
    }
}
```

In this case, looking at it directly, it is quite obvious: even though XUnit generates an independent `FixtureData` instance for each test, the singleton actually makes it so that they use the same instance.

In my case, I was looking at the test classes independently and I did not realize there was a singleton, so I assumed the problem was related with test fixtures (incorrect assumption). And because of the parts I missed when asking the question, it was impossible for someone to correctly pick up on what was wrong.

**Moral of the story:**

- Trust tested frameworks (Specially if they specialize in testing!)
- [Stop overusing singletons](https://blog.alphasmanifesto.com/2016/05/13/death-to-singletons/)
- Make sure you've got all relevant parts of the problem before asking in StackOverflow

Comment: I love followups like this, nice!

Answer (score 2):

No, you've read the docs correctly. TL;DR because Test Classes can run in parallel, the Class Fixtures *have* to be independent, that's the whole point of them.

I'd be surprised if there's a bug in xUnit wrt this as this feature/facility is stable and not undergoing change.

If you can make your actual sample fail, then, yes that's a bug in xUnit but I'm saying a) it's not failing now b) you're not going to make it fail c) SELECT is not broken ;)

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: You are *definitely* right. (Not sarcasm.) I found there was more context that was relevant and created this problem for me. I'll be providing an answer with more details of how this came to be. Thank you!